# Google slides: How to add transparency to a background image?

Tags: google-slides

How to add transparency to a background image in Google slides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gAgeAt7P8Q) is the only answer I got.

1. Insert the image as a normal image, not as a background image and make it as big as the entire background
2. Select the image, then go format and adjust the transparency
3. Right click on it and send to the back

Answer (score 0):

1. Click slide at the top
2. Click Edit Master
3. Put the image in the master slide
4. Click on the image, and click Format Options to the left of animate at the top
5. Change the transparency under the Adjustments tab
6. Right click on the image and, under the Order tab, click Send to Back OR click on the image and press ctrl + shift + down arrow
7. exit out of editing the master

It should be a transparent background image for all of your slides.